# Pronunciation of "headachy all week"

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, ipa

I was listening to this British English (BrE) clip, but I could not make out the bold words section by myself. I slowed down the clip but still couldn't make out that sound.

Do BrE speakers drop the "*k*" sound when you talk in normal speed, aka relaxed speech?
If it is not so much, could someone write down the IPA of that bold section, or record your own voice (via the link below) if you think your explanation might be tricky.

**The clip:**

Listen to the 6 sec clip [here](http://vocaroo.com/i/s1ryotPAk2sU)

**The script:**

> I've been feeling tired and **headachy all** week

Comment: I'm definite that this isn't normal stress and intonation of the speech. The guy seems to be emphasizing the "all" part, or I don't know, understating "headachy" (mainly because it was a painful experience, actually if it *is* "headachy") and this bothers me since I'm not sure.

Comment: To me, it sounds like a) bad acting & b) for some reason he seems to pronounce the 'k' closer to 'ch' which is odd to my ears. Certainly based on his accent [non-specific UK southern], it should be closer to 'k'.

Comment: I think he probably said, "I've been feeling tired and headache (the) whole week."

Answer (score 1):

That sounds pretty natural to me (Australian English native speaker).  I think the "k" sound is being modified by the "y" sound after it and is becoming softer as a result - more like "ch" as Tetsujin says..  I can't type IPA here, but when I say it myself I can feel that my tongue is further back on the roof of my mouth when I say the "k" sound in "headachy" than when I say "*headacha" or "*headacho".

Comment: Yes, the k is softened, and hurried, to get on to the Y and the A that follows it. In effect, the Y slips from a vowel sound "e" to almost a consonant Y sound: "headacheY'all week".